# Deriving a formula for a function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions

> Let $S$ := {$(x, y) ∈ \mathbb R^2: x^2 + y^2 = 1$} be the unit circle. Let $p = (−1, 0)$ ∈ $S$.
>
> Define a map $F$ from $\mathbb R$ × {$0$} to $S$ as follows: Given $(t, 0)$, let $F((t, 0)) = (x, y)$ ∈ $S$ be the intersection of $S$ with the line through $p$ and $(t, 0)$.
>
> Derive a formula for $F$.
>
> Show that $t$ → $F((t, 0))$ is a bijective map from $\mathbb R$ to $S$ \ {$p$}, and also derive a formula for its
> inverse.

How to derive a formula for $F$? If I get the line passing through $p$ and $(t,0)$, I get $(D): y = 0$ which is the x-axis

And I know that to show that $\phi$ : $\mathbb R$ →  $S$ \ {$p$}, I have to show that $\phi$ is injective and surjective

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the components have been flipped at some place(s). Probably it should have been $p = (0,-1)$, but maybe it was intended to use $\{0\} \times \mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$. (And then you should look up "stereographic projection" if you aren't yet familiar with it.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you got stuck because the problem as stated doesn't work. As pointed out in the comments by Daniel Fischer you probably want $p=(0,-1)$. In that case there is a line between $(t,0)$ and $(0,-1)$ that intersects the circle in exaclty one point and one can show that this gives a bijective map from the real line to $S\setminus \{p\}$.

Comment: And how do I derive $F$ then?

Comment: @cbcbc Can you set up the equation for the line through $(t,0)$ and (0,p)$? Then compute the intersection with the circle.

Comment: you mean through $(t,0)$ and $(0,-1)$?

Comment: Yes, made a typo $p=(0, -1)$

Comment: is the equation $y=at-1$ where $a$ is the slope?